# I have a program that doesn't work on Ubuntu, but it does on Windows

Tags: c, arrays, windows, list, compiler-errors

I have a program coded in Windows 10, and it works perfectly.
In this case (I'm going to simplify this overly because this is where the program fails), it takes a simple linked list of 200 elements (struct) and copies the data of the first 100 elements into an array of 100 elements (array[100]).
The program works perfectly on Windows, but it doesn't copy a single struct on Ubuntu.
Is there any difference between the GCC compiler from both systems that can cause this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct{
  int id;
  char title[100];
  char director[100];
  char genre[100];
  int likes;
  int number_of_voters;
  float average_rating;
  int year;
  int cost;
  char color[100];
  float ratingW;
}Movie;

struct Node{
  Movie movie;
  struct Node *next;
};

//Simply linked list
typedef struct{
  struct Node *head;
}List;

//Array
typedef struct{
  Movie movies[SIZE];
  int num;  //number of elements
}Array;

void Initialize(List *l);
void PrintList(List l);
void InsertNode(List *l, Movie reg);
void PrintMovie(Movie mov);
void PrintArray(Array arr);
void FromListToArray(List l, Array *arr);

int main(){
  List sls;
  Array a;
  Initialize(&sls);
  PrintList(sls);  //Prints 200 movies, and shows the message "Movies loaded in the list ::: 200"
  FromListToArray(sls, &a);
  PrintArray(a);  //Doesn't print any movie, and shows the message "Movies loaded in the array ::: 0"
  return 0;
}

//Initializes the list
void Initialize(List *l){
  l->head = NULL;
}

void PrintList(List l){
  struct Node *p;
  p = l.head;
  while(p != NULL)
  {
    PrintMovie(p->movie);
    p = p->next;
  }
}

//Inserts a node at the beginning of the list
void InsertNode(List *l, Movie reg){
  struct Node *r;
  r = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));;
  if (r == NULL){
    printf("No memory!\n");
  }
  else{
    r->movie.id = reg.id;
    strcpy(r->movie.title, reg.title);
    strcpy(r->movie.director, reg.director);
    strcpy(r->movie.genre, reg.genre);
    r->movie.likes = reg.likes;
    r->movie.number_of_voters = reg.number_of_voters;
    r->movie.average_rating = reg.average_rating;
    r->movie.year = reg.year;
    r->movie.cost = reg.cost;
    strcpy(r->movie.color, reg.color);
    r->movie.ratingW = reg.ratingW;
    r->next = l->head;
    l->head = r;
  }
}

/*Copies the data from a txt file into a simply linked list. 
Line 1 is the id of the first movie, line 2 the title... line 10 is the color. 
Line 11 is the id of the second movie, and so on... This repeated 200 times (200 movies = 2000 lines)*/
void FromTxtToList(List *l, FILE *f){
  int j = 0;
  char cad[100];
  Movie reg;
  f = fopen("movies.txt", "r");
  if (f == NULL){
    printf("Error, could not open the file\n");
  }
  else{
    while(!feof(f)){
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      reg.id = atoi(cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      strcpy(reg.title, cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      strcpy(reg.director, cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      strcpy(reg.genre, cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      reg.likes = atoi(cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      reg.number_of_voters = atoi(cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      reg.average_rating = atof(cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      reg.year = atoi(cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      reg.cost = atoi(cad);
      fgets(cad, 100, f);
      strcpy(reg.color, cad);
      reg.ratingW = 0;
      InsertNode(l, reg);
      j++;
    }
  }
  fclose(f);
  printf("Movies loaded in the list ::: %d\n", j);
}

void PrintMovie(Movie mov){
  printf("///////////////////////////////////\n");
  printf("Id: %d\n", mov.id);
  printf("Title: %s", mov.title);
  printf("Director: %s", mov.director);
  printf("Genre: %s", mov.genre);
  printf("Likes: %d\n", mov.likes);
  printf("Number of voters: %d\n", mov.number_of_voters);
  printf("Average rating: %.2f\n", mov.average_rating);
  printf("Year: %d\n", mov.year);
  printf("Cost: $%d\n", mov.cost);
  printf("Color or BW: %s", mov.color);
  printf("Rating: %.2f\n", mov.ratingW);
  printf("///////////////////////////////////\n");
}

void PrintArray(Array arr){
  int i;
  printf("\nArray: \n");
  for(i=0; i < arr.num; i++){
    PrintMovie(arr.movies[i])
  }
}

void FromListToArray(List l, Array *arr){
  int i = 0;
  arr->num = 0;
  struct Node *p;
  p = l.head;
  while ((p != NULL) && (arr->num < SIZE)){
    if (strcmp(p->movie.color, "Color\n")==0){  
    //If I find a "colored" movie (color = "Color")
      //Copy the data into the array
      arr->movies[i].id = p->movie.id;
      strcpy(arr->movies[i].title, p->movie.title);
      strcpy(arr->movies[i].director, p->movie.director);
      strcpy(arr->movies[i].genre, p->movie.genre);
      arr->movies[i].likes = p->movie.likes;
      arr->movies[i].number_of_voters = p->movie.number_of_voters;
      arr->movies[i].average_rating = p->movie.average_rating;
      arr->movies[i].year = p->movie.year;
      arr->movies[i].cost = p->movie.cost;
      strcpy(arr->movies[i].color, p->movie.color);
      arr->movies[i].ratingW = p->movie.ratingW;
      arr->num++;
      i++;
    }
    p = p->next;
  }
  printf("Movies loaded in the array ::: %d\n", arr->num);
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but it's overwhelmingly more likely that you have a UB bug:(

Comment: Also,  it's that 'doesn't compile' != 'doesn't work correctly when run'

Comment: @Martin James UB?

Comment: We'd definitely need to see the snippet of code in question.  Also, how do you know the data isn't being copied?

Comment: For us to help you, we need a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: UB: **Undefined Behaviour**, see [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) or [c2 wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?UndefinedBehavior)

Comment: UB means that you are doing something that is undefined and the nice windows guys made an assumption about what you wanted it to do

Comment: One might be a debugging version. The undefined behaviour does not have to give the same result on both systems (or even be consistent on one system).

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: Yeah.... 'while ((p != NULL)' ... you really sure that sls is correctly initialized/loaded?  Check with your debugger.

Comment: @Martin James Yeah. I have a function to print the list (it prints the 200 movies correctly), and I looked what happens if I print p->movie (in the FromListToArrayt function, after p = l.head) and it prints the first movie correctly. So I'm sure the list is loaded correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure.  There may be something to `//sls already with the content I want, 200 structs Movie` that we're not seeing.   A [mcve] would confirm this.

Comment: `FromListToArray(sls, &a);` causes undefined behaviour (`sls` is uninitialized and you pass it by value)

Comment: @M.M It is initialized, because it has contents, I just didn't include the function here.

Comment: Ok I added some more functions, I think that should cover all the code with the problem I'm having.

Comment: Would you mind to provide a (small) example of the input file? And I don't think that `Initialize(&sls); PrintList(sls);` will print any movie.

Comment: @thebusybee [this](https://i.imgur.com/u8jUFiX.png) is what the file looks like. Although keep in mind that since `InsertNode` inserts at the beginning, the last movie of the file will be the first node. Inverse order.

Comment: Well, please [edit] your question with an excerp of the input file. I'm afraid no-one would like to type all that lines by hand. And where in your [example] is the `List sls` filled before the call of `PrintList(sls)`?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, in function `PrintArray`

there is a miising ";" in the line `PrintMovie(arr.movies[i])`.

**Second**, there is an issue with `while(!feof(f))` in the function `FromTxtToList`.

Apparently feof() is TRUE only after the end of file (EOF) is read, not when EOF is reached. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299296/how-to-use-feoffile-f) and [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-58.html).

A possible fix could be `if(fgets(cad, 100, f)==NULL) break;`

instead of `fgets(cad, 100, f);`

in function `FromTxtToList`.

**Also** the movies.txt file should end with only one empty line (otherwise you will get "Color" instead of "Color\n" for the last movie).